# Why is operator norm defined the way it is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Is there an intuition for the infimum definition of ${\| A \|}_{\mathrm{op}}$ without using a different, equivalent definition?**

I am referring to the definition, given an operator $A: W \rightarrow V$, $$ {\| A \|}_{\mathrm{op}} = \inf \{ c \geq 0 : \| A v \| \leq c \| v \|, \ \forall v \in V \}.$$

---

Note that the $\sup$ definition, $$ \| A \|_{\mathrm{op}} = \sup \{ \| A v \| : v \in V, \| v \| =1 \},$$ agrees more with my intuition and I know that one can prove they are equivalent (as I have done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171259/equivalent-definitions-of-the-operator-norm)), but that exercise seems conceptually unrevealing.

---

To me the $\inf$ definition reads as choosing the smallest $c$ that bounds all vectors, however my current intuition thinks that its a better question to think about how large $A$ makes things, so rather a maximum.

I guess trivially this means things are always bounded by infinity but my point is that it doesn't really answer or correct my wrong intuition. I still feel the size of $A$ should be some sort of question about how it makes things large, so why do we consider the smallest?

Comment: I don't know what else you are asking for; the inf in your first formula equals the sup in the second, so they are simply two ways of writing the same thing.

Comment: If you want $A$ to be bounded (equivalently continuous) then you do not want $A$ to make things too "large", which is why we take an infimum. Another way to think of $||A||_{op}$ is the smallest constant for which $A$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't want proves. What I am looking for is if there is a way to explain/argue why ||||≤|||| for all ∈ is a good definition directly without referencing other stuff? Somehow the minimum is a good definition. Why? Can that be justified directly?

Comment: @nammie right, I am asking exactly why the Liptschitz continuous definition makes sense directly rather than appealing to equivalent definitions that seem to stand conceptually on their own.

Comment: You can find other textbooks, where your sup formula is used as the definition, and it is then proved to be equal to the inf formula.

Comment: @GEdgar I know the proves. Thats not what i am looking for. I am looking for a conceptual justification for the infimum definition on its own.

Comment: @Pinocchio One way this definition is useful is when you want to compute the value of $||A||_{op}$. Say you know that $||A||_{op} \geq c$. If you can construct a sequence $(v_n)$ so that $||A(v_n)|| \leq (c + 1/n)||v_n||$, then you have $||A||_{op} = c$.

Answer (score 2):

In the first formulation, the $c$ gives an upper bound to how much the vector may grow (that's what $\le$ means). Taking the infimum then says that you want the *lowest* upper bound to the vector's growth.

Now remember what the supremum is: The supremum of a set is, by definition, the lowest upper bound to that set. In other words, by asking for the lowest upper bound, you are really asking for the *supremum* of the vector's growth.

Indeed, you can make this quite explicit in the formulas:

Start with the definition you gave:

$$\| A \|_{\rm op} = \inf \{ c \geq 0 : \| A v\| \leq c \|v\|, \forall v \in V \}$$

Now we observe that the zero vector doesn't constrain $c$ in any way. Therefore let's remove that from the considered set.

$$\| A \|_{\rm op} = \inf \{ c \geq 0 : \| A v\| \leq c \|v\|, \forall v \in V\setminus\{0\} \}$$

Now that we have excluded the zero vector, we see that $\|v\| > 0$, therefore we can divide the inequality by it without changing anything. This gives:

$$\| A \|_{\rm op} = \inf \left\{ c \geq 0 : \frac{\| A v\|}{\|v\|} \leq c , \forall v \in V\setminus\{0\} \right\}$$

But now the right hand side explicitly describes the lowest upper bound to $\|Av\|/\|v\|$, that is,

$$\| A \|_{\rm op} = \sup \left\{ \frac{\| A v\|}{\|v\|} : v \in V\setminus\{0\} \right\}$$

And here you've got your supremum.

Note again that in the last step, I did nothing but literally apply the definition of the supremum.

Answer (score 1):

The definition with the $\inf$ resembles the one used for constructing the [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) which, in turn, plays a key role in the proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem.  The definition of the functional is carried out without using a norm, hence has meaning in any real vector space, normed or not.  *It is the use of the $\inf$ construct that allows to define the functional without the norm*.

See, for example, Section 4.14 in [*Introductory Real Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cbbCAgAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s), or the first chapter in Brezis's textbook on functional analysis, or Section 3.8 in [*Fundamentals of Functional Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OvLqCAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Answer (score 1):

**An informal, but hopefully intuitive, answer:**

Write $\partial B_{r}$ for the set $\{ v \in V \ | \ \| v \| = r \}$. Think of the dotted hexagon as being $A(\partial B_{1})$ (the result of applying $A$ to $\partial B_{1}$), and think of the blue circle as being $\partial B_{{\| A \|}_{\mathrm{op}}}$.

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

To find ${\| A \|}_{\mathrm{op}}$, you can either find the biggest value of $\| A v \|$ for $v \in \partial B_{1}$, or the smallest $c$ such that $\partial B_{c} \supseteq A(\partial B_{1})$. The $\sup$ definition is the first method, and the $\inf$ definition is the second method.

The $\inf$ definition has $\partial B$ start out at infinity and shrink down to the smallest $c \geq 0$ so that $\partial B_{c}$ still contains $A(\partial B_{1})$, which is exactly the same as the smallest $c \geq 0$ so that $\| A v \| \leq c \| v \|$ $\forall v \in V$.