# Symmetric positive definitine matrix $I-X^TX$ => $X^TX<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

If $I-X^{\top}X$ is symmetric positive definite, why is $\lVert X \rVert < 1$?
It seems logically to me but why does it follow?

It's
$v^{ \top} ( I - X^{ \top } X ) v
=
\lVert v \rVert^2 - \lVert X v \rVert^2      > 0$....

(An attempt was $- \lVert X v \rVert^2   \geq - \lVert X \rVert^2  \cdot  \lVert v \rVert^2 $ but it doesn't help..)

Answer (score 3):

Well,
$$
I - X^\top X \succ 0 \implies v^\top(I-X^\top X)v > 0 \implies \lVert v \rVert^2 > \lVert Xv\rVert^2 \implies \frac{\lVert Xv\rVert^2}{\lVert v \rVert^2} < 1, \forall v \neq 0.
$$

But by the definition of the norm
$$
\lVert X \rVert = \sup_{v\neq 0} \frac{\lVert X v\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert} = \max_{\lVert v\rVert=1} \{\lVert Xv\rVert\}< 1.
$$

For the equivalence
$$
\sup_{v\neq 0} \frac{\lVert X v\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert} = \sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1} \{\lVert Xv\rVert\}
$$ see [Equivalent Definitions of the Operator Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171259/equivalent-definitions-of-the-operator-norm),
The equivalence
$$
\sup_{\lVert v\rVert} \{\lVert Xv\rVert\} = \max_{\lVert v\rVert} \{\lVert Xv\rVert\},
$$
follows from the fact that $X:V\to W$ is continuous, and $\{v\in V~\vert~ \lVert v \rVert = 1\}$ is a compact set (assuming that $V$ finite dimensional), as pointed out by Drew Brady.

Comment: This argument is not fully rigorous. $f(v) < c$ for all $v \neq 0$ does not in general imply that $\sup_{v \neq 0} f(v) < c$.

Answer (score 2):

**Warm-up** (Non-strict inequality)**.** $\quad$ If $I-X^T X \succeq 0$, then $X^T X \preceq I$.

Therefore, we conclude that for each $\xi$ such that $\|\xi\| = 1$,
$$
\|X\xi\|^2 = \xi^T X^T X \xi \leq \xi^T I \xi = \|\xi\|^2 = 1. 
$$
Consequently, $\|X\| = \sup_{\|\xi\| = 1} \|X \xi \| \leq 1$.

**Strict inequality:** $\quad$Suppose now that $I - X^T X \succ 0$. Then $X^T X \prec I$.
By compactness, there exists a $\xi_\star$ of unit norm such that
$$
\|X\| = \|X \xi_\star\| = \sqrt{\xi_\star^T X^T X \xi_\star} 
< \sqrt{\xi_\star^T I \xi_\star} = 1. 
$$
This gives the strict inequality as required.

Comment: The question requires $\|X\|<1$

Comment: @Gribouillis updated.

Comment: I guess it would be nice to show the equivalence $\sup_{v\neq 0} \frac{\lVert Xv\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}= \max_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}\{ \lVert Xv \rVert\}$. Otherwise your answer is just as rigorous as mine.

Comment: There's nothing to show. They're the same set of values. I.e., Define the set $S = \{ \|Xv\|/\|v\| : v \neq 0\}$ and $T = \{\|Xv\| : \|v\| = 1\}$. They're clearly the same (and therefore their suprema coincide)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and write $X^TX=Q^TDQ$ where $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal and $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the diagonal matrix $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1 , \ldots ,\lambda _m)$ with $\lambda _j \geq 0$ for all $1\leq j \leq n$. Since $I-X^TX=Q^T\big(I-D\big)Q$ is positive definite and $I-D=\text{diag}(1-\lambda _1 ,\ldots ,1-\lambda _n )$ we have $1-\lambda_j>0$ for all $j$. Therefore $\lambda_j \in [0,1)$ for all $j$ which means so is $M=\max_{1 \leq j \leq n}\lambda _j$.

Now choose $v\in \mathbb{R}^n, ||v||=1$ and set $w=Qv=(w, \ldots ,w_n)^T$. The orthogonality of $Q$ implies $||w||=1$ too. We get $$||Xv||^2=w^TDw=\lambda_1 w_1^2 + \dots + \lambda _n w_n^2\leq M||w||^2<1$$ Hence $||Xv||<1$ for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $||v||=1$ and by compactness of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have the result.