# Application of corollary of Banach-Steinhaus theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is the corollary of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem:

> **Corollary A**: Let $A\subseteq X$ be a set in $X$ such that for every $f\in X^*$ there exists a constant $C(f)$ such that $\sup_{x\in A}|f(x)|\leq C(f)$. Then $A$ is norm bounded, i.e., there exists a constant $C$ such that $\|x\|\leq C$ for all $x\in A$.

The author then applies **Corollary A** via the following theorem and proof:

> **Theorem 1**: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A\colon H\to H$ be a linear operator with $\text{Dom}A=H$ (not necessarily bounded) and $A=A^*$, i.e.,
> $\langle Ax,y \rangle= \langle x,Ay \rangle$. Then $A$ is bounded.
>
> *Proof*. We have
> $$
> |\langle Ax,y \rangle| = |\langle x,Ay \rangle|\leq\|x\|\cdot\|Ay\|\leq\|Ay\|
> $$
> for all $x\in H$ with $\|x\|\leq1$ and for all $y\in H$. By **Corollary A** we conclude that the set $\{Ax:\|x\|\leq1\}$ is bounded which implies $\|Ax\|\leq C\|x\|$.

However this proof confused me. Can anyone really explain what is going on in this proof, i.e., what is the set $A$ supposed to be from **Corollary A**. Also, why does this even finish the proof? Don't we have to show the operator $A$ is bounded for every $x\in H$, not just those $x$ with $\|x\|\leq1$? Or does this finish to proof since it's enough to show the operator $A$ is bounded for $x=0$, and clearly $\|x=0\|\leq1$...?

---

I should add that, I take it the set $A$ is supposed to be $A:=\{Ax:\|x\|\leq1\}$; however, then this set being norm bounded means there exists $C>0$ such that $\|Ax\|\leq C$ for all $Ax\in A$, so also $\|x\|\leq 1$. But how does $\|Ax\|\leq C$ together with $\|x\|\leq1$ give $\|Ax\|\leq C\|x\|$?

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||x||$ and $\|x\|$ is not conspicuous enough to you, look at the difference between $||x|| ||y||$ and $\|x\|\|y\|.$ The former is coded as `||x|| ||y||` and the latter as `\|x\|\|y\|`. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that $A$ is overloaded to be both a set and an operator. Let me call the linear operator $T$ instead.

Define the set $A = \{Tx: \|x\| \leq 1\}$. Since every linear functional on $H$ is of the form $\langle \cdot, y\rangle$ by the Riesz Representation Theorem, the calculation in the proof of Theorem 1 tells you that for every $f \in H^*$, $sup_{\{Tx: \|x\| \leq 1\}} |f(Tx)| \leq C(f) = \|Ty\|$ where $y$ is the element of $H$ corresponding to $f$ via the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Hence, by Corollary A, $\{Tx: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is a bounded set. Therefore the operator norm of $T$ is finite.

---

Rereading the question, it seems you might not have seen the various equivalent representations of the operator norm. In this case, for arbitrary $x \neq 0$, let $z = \|x\|^{-1} x$. Then $z$ has norm at most $1$ so that $\|Tz\| \leq C$ for the constant $C$ bounding the set above. Multiplying through by $\|x\|$ yields $\|Tx\| \leq C\|x\|$ as desired.

In general, it might be worth googling/checking a standard text to see the various equivalent forms of the operator norm if you have not seen these before.

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Let me ask this just for the sake of clarification: We do need $\|Tx\|\leq C\|x\|$ for every $x\in H$? And this can be done by taking any $x\in H$ and letting $z:=x/\|x\|\in H$. Then we have $\|z\|=1$ so $Tz\in A$, and by the boundedness of the set $A$, $\|Tz\|\leq C$, whence $\|Tx\|\leq C\|x\|$ for any $x\in H$. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on which definition of the operator norm you wrote down to start with, but they are all equivalent. You should read e.g. this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171259/equivalent-definitions-of-the-operator-norm (which I found by googling, as suggested in my answer)

Comment: Are you saying the question "do we need $\|Tx\|\leq C\|x\|$ for every $x\in H$", depends on which of the operator norms one writs down to start with? I do see/know that they are all equivalent.

Comment: I am saying that the statement you have written will be true, but one does not need to directly check that statement since it is implied by any of the other definitions of the operator norm being finite. In practice, you will just pick the most convenient of the equivalent definitions for a given problem and check that rather than always try to get to this one.